# Who is this 90s Marvel comic character that has three bodies?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, avengers

I was an avid comic reader in the 90s and distinctly recall a hero/side character that appeared in an Avengers comic who appeared to have three bodies. The bodies looked very different with one having brown hair, a beard, and a flannel like shirt. I cannot recall any distinct details about the other bodies except that they appeared together. They moved as one entity standing in a triangular pattern and they mimicked each others actions. I also seem to recall that this Avengers comic was when Vision was solid white. The scene in particular that I recall, they were explaining something to the Avengers.

Who is this character?

Comment: By "three bodies", do you mean that they were literally joined (like conjoined twins and triplets) or is it more that they simply stood in a triangular formation and moved in time with each other? https://media.gettyimages.com/id/sb10065788a-001/photo/three-business-people-standing-in-triangle-formation.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=gi&k=20&c=XLgwkaBCbxqPaVZULBQwWSSlXBA6Uh8wr-CaIVJVVa8=

Comment: [Tri-sentinel](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tri-Sentinel) featured in Acts of Vengeance alongside White Vision, but I don't think he matches your description very well

Comment: One of these, possibly; https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Characters?from=Toxin+II+%28Symbiote%29+%28Earth-TRN00461%29%0AToxin+II+%28Symbiote%29+%28Earth-TRN461%29

Comment: @Valorum Your gettyimages link is EXACTLY how they stood. I wish I could recall more information about the character. I looked at all the "tri" characters on the fandom and did not find him listed. I'll edit and pull the "tri" reference from the original post.

Comment: Can you name any other Avengers who appeared in that issue?

Comment: @LogicDictates Not with any certainty. I do not believe the character was involved in any combat scenes. I'm fairly certain it was a comic that John Byrne was involved in. I no longer have access to my childhood collection, I just haven't met anyone who can remember this particular character.

Comment: As far as I know, Byrne's Avengers work in the '90s was limited to a stint as writer and artist on _West Coast Avengers Vol. 2 #42-57_ (1989-1990) and _Avengers Vol. 1 #305-317_ (1989-1990). Those runs did coincide with the Vision's pale yellow colour scheme, but I checked both and couldn't find anything matching your description.

Comment: I do know he worked on a few of the Fantastic Four comics. I wonder if there is a chance that I have the Avenger's tower confused with the Fantastic Four's tower in my head. I have yet to find any reference or picture confirming the character I am describing as well.

Comment: Byrne's FF run spanned _Fantastic Four Vol. 1 #232-294_ (1981-1986). The Vision didn't adopt the white/pale yellow colour scheme until _West Coast Avengers Vol. 2 #45_ (1989).